# Django: No such table while rewriting the "User" class

Tags: python, django

I'm making a Django project with Django 3.1.

I was trying to rewrite the `User` class in Django. This is what I wrote in `app_questions/models.py`:

```py
import django.contrib.auth.models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    #pass
```

`settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app_questions',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_questions.User'
```

Also I created an `superuser` before I did these all.

After that I did `makemigrations` and `migrate` in the cmd and ran the server. I open the admin page and try to edit the `User` I created beforehand, but when I click the edit page, this error occured:

```
OperationalError at /admin/app_questions/user/1/change/
no such table: app_questions_user_groups
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app_questions/user/1/change/
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: app_questions_user_groups
Exception Location: C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 413, in execute
Python Executable:  C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\*\\django_sample\\vitural_env\\zeaf',
 'C:\\Users\\*\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\*\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\*\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\*\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\*\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I found a few posts to solve this. These are methods I tried:

1. `makemigrations` and `migrate` (same error)
2. `migrate (appname) --fake` (same error)
3. Add things into the `User` class (error in /admin: `no such column`)
4. `migrate --sync-db` (same error)
5. `migrate --run-syncdb` (same error)
6. `$ manage.py (appname) zero` (failed: `Unknown command`)
7. `migrate --fake (appname) zero` (same error)

They all didn't solve the problem. Posts in 2016 or 2017 seems doesn't work anymore for now.

Any help is appreciated & sorry if this is a duplicated post.

Comment: Have you done anything in your `app_questions` app which includes user groups?

Comment: I've wrote `new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=mail, password=password, level=1)` `new_user.save()` in a function in views.py; And I don't see any other thing else that involves `User` object. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Please add Installed_apps to your question where in your settings.py

Comment: @OsmanDurdag Added

Comment: are you sure you are referring to the new `User` model in no `app_questions/admin.py`?

Comment: Can you check if the actual table exists in the database? If not you could write a custom migration to add it

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb Here's a part of codes I wrote in admin.py: `from .models import User` `class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): list_display = ['email']` `admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)` Is that what you mean?

Comment: @mousetail Sorry, how do I check the database directly?

Comment: `python manage.py dbshell`

Comment: It depends on what database you are using how to check your tables, but a quick google search should help you further

Comment: `CommandError: You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path.` Should I install Sqlite3 first or something...?

Comment: That means either the CLI is not installed or not on your `path` indeed. Note the CLI is independent from the python module

Comment: Your IDE may also include a DB inspector

Comment: I installed a DB inspector now. What should I do now?

Comment: Have you ever migrated before adding the user model?

Comment: Yes. Also I changed the app name before with some edit in the `migration` folder. I don't know if that would cause the file corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the first `migrate` command, all the default migrations would come into effect which means all the **tables and relationships would be created**.

When you are customizing the default `User` (overriding the default `User` model and providing a value to `AUTH_USER_MODEL`) **all the relationships would change**.

> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL after you’ve created database tables is significantly more difficult since **it affects foreign keys and many-to-many relationships**

Changing the user model mid-way is not recommended as you need to manually fix your database schema.

The simplest way to fix this, if you changed the User model mid-way would be: deleting all the migrations, database and running makemigrations and migrate commands. Which created a fresh database schema.

This is a limitation which is said in the docs as:

> Due to limitations of Django’s dynamic dependency feature for swappable models, the model referenced by AUTH_USER_MODEL must be created in the first migration of its app (usually called 0001_initial); otherwise, you’ll have dependency issues.

From Docs:

- [Custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)
- [Changing to a custom user model mid-project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project)

**The best practice is to create the custom User model at the start of the project and then migrate and work on the User model later in case anything related to the authentication or User model are to be changed later**

Answer (score 1):

If i right understood, you had already your project running, that is the makemigration is not the first makemigration.
If so try delete the database and run makemigration again, maybe in a test dev environment, just to check the problem. If this work (and should) you've found the problem.
If you don't want to delete the database, maybe you could [extend user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) instead of overwriting.

Comment: Thank you it works. But may you explain what was the problem that cause the error?

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means that something has gone wrong with your migrations, and often happens when you try to make changes like these after the fact. One possible solution is to delete all your migration files except for the one ending in `initial.py`. Then `makemigrations` and `migrate` again and it should work.

Comment: I remember I tried this before but it doesn't work. Now I tried again and this error happened: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "django_admin_log" already exists`